# Symfony 2 - Agregar campo user_id a la tabla session al momento de guardar a sesion

Tags: session, symfony

Estoy intentando guardar el campo user_id en la tabla de session en el momento en que agrega la sesion a la DB.

para esto agregue un campo en la tabla "session", y modifique el config.yml agregando el campo SESS_USER_ID.

Luego le inyecto el serivicio @security.context para obtener el user_id

en mi config.yml

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.db_session

parameters:
    oci8.db_options:
        db_table:       SESSIONS
        db_id_col:      SESS_ID
        db_data_col:    SESS_DATA
        db_user_id_col: SESS_USER_ID
        db_time_col:    SESS_TIME
services:
    session.handler.db_session:
        class:     App\CoreBundle\Handler\DoctrineSessionHandler
        arguments: ["@doctrine.dbal.default_connection", "%oci8.db_options%" "@security.context"]
```

En  DoctrineSessionHandler:

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext

```
public function __construct(Connection $dbalConnection, array $dbOptions = array(), SecurityContext $context){
$this->context = $context

$user = $this->context->getToken()->getUser();
```

En este caso me dice lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea como puedo obtener el usuario??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el usuario que está conectado, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Con esto es suficiente, ya obtendrías el objeto del usuario.

---

Desde Symfony 2.6, el servicio *secuity.context* no se usa, se utiliza *security.token_storage* de la siguiente manera:

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()
```

Puedes leer un poco más en [esta respuesta en inglés.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680917/how-do-i-get-the-entity-that-represents-the-current-user-in-symfony2)